# Android SQLite reading raws with wait time

Tags: android, sqlite, time, delay

I have a small problem I'm using SQLite and my problem is that when I run the program the code reads all the rows in the table. How can I make it to read 1 then delay and read the next then delay?

Note: `delay = 5 sec` for example.

```
//---get all titles---
db.open();
Cursor c = db.getAllTitles();
if (c.moveToFirst())
{
    do 
    {          
        DisplayTitle(c);
    } while (c.moveToNext());
}
db.close();
```

This is how I display them:

```
public void DisplayTitle(Cursor c)
{
    Toast.makeText(this,
            "id: " + c.getString(0) + "\n" +
                    "ISBN: " + c.getString(1) + "\n" +
                    "TITLE: " + c.getString(2) + "\n" +
                    "PUBLISHER:  " + c.getString(3),
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the accepted answer in this post for an idea on how to use a Handler to create a pseudo loop that calls itself repeated on a delay. It shouldn't be too hard to implement something similar for your needs.

[android substuting the click with a timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5671984/android-substuting-the-click-with-a-timer/5672264#5672264)

Comment: im sorry to ask again but i tried it and for some reason its not working can you please provide an example ......i maybe doing it wrong because im new to android ....thank you