# Updating Android widgets every 1 minute

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm writing an Android widget. I want to update it every 1-5 minutes to monitor data from web service but I discovered that `android:updatePeriodMillis` cannot be less than 30 minutes.

How can I obtain this result with a widget?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Register an AlarmManager service for every 1 min call.

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(context, UpdateService.class);
final PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, 0);
final AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarm.cancel(pending);
long interval = 1000*60;
alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(),interval, pending);
```

However, pushing updates to app widgets is an expensive operation. Updating every 1 min would force your "update an app widget" code to be resident in memory which keeps running all of the time, and this will also eat up battery pretty significantly.

Comment: Where are we supposed to put this code? As an android beginner, it doesn't help me...

Comment: is this should be put in the `onUpdate` method?

Comment: This does not work properly for Android 6.0+ .
Doze mode generally does not work well with `setRepeating()` . I tried everything, even `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle()` everytime time the alarm goes off, but the it keeps either not going off, or going off too much time after the 1 minute i want.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`Handler`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) to `sendMessageDelayed(..)` a message or `postDelayed(..)` a `Runner`.

```
new Handler().postDelayed( new Runnable() {
    public void run() { ... },
    60000 /* one minute */
);
```

Comment: The accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5671984/android-substuting-the-click-with-a-timer/5672264#5672264 gives a pretty good example of using a Handler and postDelayed

Comment: This assumes you have code constantly running that will be updating the app widget. This is either a flawed assumption or a really bad idea.

Comment: If the user means desktop widget, as in the android.appwidget class, then yes, I agree, the Priyank's answer is correct.  However, if the user means custom view, such as something from the android.widget class, then that implies a View tree attached to a Activity, which was my original assumption. (Why oh why did they oveload the "widget" name?)